# Get dynamic svg content

Tags: javascript, svg

I use [snapsvg](http://snapsvg.io) library for svg generation from external svg parts. Here is main container:

```
<svg id="mainContent"></svg>
```

When I look into this element using inspector I see new dynamic svg elements appended inside.

[image]

How can I get this svg full dynamic content to save it into file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have to tried just simply query it like normal dom element?

```
var content = document.querySelector('#mainContent').outerHTML
```

for download part, you can use `saveAs` function for modern browser

```
var blob = new Blob([content], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
saveAs(blob, "download.svg");
```

see https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

[image]

Comment: are you querying before the content being rendered?

Comment: @Manivannan then use `outerHTML` instead

Answer (score 0):

Following code snippet could help u to download the svg file.

`function download(filename, text) {
       var element = document.createElement('a');
       element.setAttribute('href','data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent('<svg>'+text+'</svg>'));
       element.setAttribute('download', filename);
       element.style.display = 'none';
       document.body.appendChild(element);
       element.click();
       document.body.removeChild(element);
     }               download("samplesvg.svg",document.getElementById('mainContent').innerHTML);`